# How to redirect a Link to a new tab in contact form 7?

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I was trying to redirect my contact form 7 to specific pdf link. But I m not sure how to open it in new tab can someone help me up with the same ?

Below is my code...

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
if ( '876' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
    location = 'https://spilledsunshine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/10-Reminders-To-Myself-By-Ishita-Mehta.pdf';
    target = '_blank';
}
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

target = '_blank'; is not working is there any other option to open in new tab ?

Comment: I don't think that's actually setting target=_blank on anything - you're just making a JavaScript variable and not using it anywhere. In any case you probably need to set it on the <form> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You got it right,

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

The `_blank` directive [opens the link in a New window/tab](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) depending on the browser setting.  This is only way to achieve your redirect in a new tab, but is entirely dependent on the user's browser setting over which you have no control.

Anyhow, it's [not recommended](https://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/#a-bad-reason-the-link-is-to-a-pdf) to open pdf in a new window/tab.